# Webpack skipping .less file in next.js in app router

Tags: webpack, next.js, less, less-loader

```js
const { StatsWriterPlugin } = require('webpack-stats-plugin')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
/**
 * @type {import('next').NextConfig} nextConfig
 */
const nextConfig = {
    reactStrictMode: true,
    webpack: (config, options) => {
        config.stats = 'verbose';
        const { dev, isServer } = options;

        // Output webpack stats JSON file only for 
        // client-side/production build
        if (!dev && !isServer) {
            config.plugins.push(
                new StatsWriterPlugin({
                    filename: '../webpack-stats.json',
                    stats: {
                        assets: true,
                        chunks: true,
                        modules: true
                    }
                })
            );
        }
        config.optimization = {
            ...config.optimization,
            splitChunks: {
                cacheGroups: {
                    styles: {
                        name: "styles",
                        type: "css/mini-extract",
                        chunks: "all",
                        enforce: true,
                    },
                },
            },
        };
        config.plugins.push(
            new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                filename: "static/css/[name].css",
            })
        );
        config.module.rules.push(
            {
                test: /\.(scss|less|sass|css)$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader"
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "sass-loader",
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true,
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "postcss-loader",
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true,
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "less-loader",
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true,
                            lessOptions: {
                                javascriptEnabled: true,
                            }
                        }
                    },
                ],
            });
        return config;
    },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

My layout.tsx

```
import type { Metadata } from "next";
// import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
const styles = require("./appStyles.less");
// import "./globals.css";
// import "./styles/importer.less"
import Header from "@/components/Header";
import Footer from "@/components/Footer";
import { Toaster } from "react-hot-toast";

// const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "FPMS",
  description: "Frequency Planning & Management System",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/dependencies/bootstrap-4/bootstrap-4.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/dependencies/fontawesome.css" />
        {/* <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/globals.css" /> */}
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="page-wrap" className="login">
          <Header />
          <div id="view-wrap" className="container">
            {children}
            <Toaster />
          </div>
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

If I edit the .less file to have a compilation error then the sass-loader will throw an error in the dev mode. When there are no errors, the less file is not even converted/nor included in the css, however the globals.css is, if included in index.tsx

The webpack-stats.json shows no sign of `appStyless.less` and I also have no idea how to debug to see which loader fails to generate output or where is everything breaking down.
Apparently all works without the app router.